# C# Programming practice

Tags: c#, oop, methods

I want to update a control based on a value e.g:

```
       if (StringName == StringName2) 
            ListBox1.Items.Add("send data");
        else if (StringName3 == StringName4)
            DifferentListBox.Items.Add("send data");
        else if (StringName5 == StringName3)
            AnotherListBox.Items.Add("send data");
```

Or done using a switch statement and so on another 20 times for example.

Is it possible to put these methods `(OneOfTheListBoxes.Items.Add("send data")` to be put
in a dictionary so i only need to enter the key to action the method instead of iterating through each statement.

Or can you point me to a practice that would make me achieve this? Or how to achieve this in less code?

Comment: Is it intentional that you are comparing different strings, e.g. (StringName == StringName2) vs. (StringName3 == StringName4)?  This makes a big difference to the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you could put all the of the listboxes into a dictionary like so;

```
Dictionary<string, ListBox> _Dictionary;

public Something() //constructor
{
   _Dictionary= new Dictionary<string, ListBox>();
   _Dictionary.add("stringname1", ListBox1);
   _Dictionary.add("stringname2", ListBox2);
   _Dictionary.add("stringname3", ListBox3);
}


....


public void AddToListBox(string listBoxName, string valueToAdd)
{
  var listBox = _Dictionary[listBoxName];
  listBox.Items.Add(valueToAdd);
}
```

Comment: damn it! you beat me to it...+1

Comment: Kirschstein has a great solution. If annakata's (below) point is valid: you're testing against different strings, you can still use this solution as long as there is a 1:* string:ListBox relationship, just enter the ListBox more than once in the Dictionary.

e.g.,

_Dictionary.Add("string1", ListBox1);
_Dictionary.Add("string2", ListBox1);

Comment: @North, not a problem!
@Mark, I noticed the comparing of different strings a little while after I posted and started looking for a solution to it if this was the case, quite tricky!

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Use dictionary with the key holding a StringName, and value holding a Listbox.
Then use:

```
myDict[StringName].Items.Add("send data")
```